# python decorator - registering class within base

Tags: python

I've been searching the web for a solution to this problem but haven't found anything elegant.

Lets say I have a base class that has a registry which the derived classes can use as a decorator in order to register their methods:

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._content = {}

    def run_them_all(self):
        for key, content in self._content.items():
            print(key, content)

    # This should be the registery function
    def register(old_method, key):
        self._content[key] = old_method()


class Derived(Base):
    @Base.register("some other content")
    def do_something(self):
        return {"name": "yes"}

    @Base.register("some_content")
    def do_something_else(self):
        return {"hi": "ho"}

    def this_should_not_be_registered(self):
        return "yooo"


derived = Derived("John")
derived.run_them_all()
```

Is it possible to achiev this?
Having a normal decorator expects a explicit function call in order to create the detour. But I simply want to register this calls for later use or at least register their return values to be used for later without directly calling those methods myself.

This should result in:

```
{"some other content": {"name": "yes"}}
{"some content": {"hi": "ho"}}
```

I simply want to avoid overriding the run_them_all like this:

```
class Derived(Base):
    ...

    def run_them_all(self):
        self._content["some_content"] = self.do_something_else()
        ...
        return self._content
```

Comment: clarify your problem your description makes little sense and I don't see any reason why you couldn't just use a decorator function instead of a decorator class to handle this.  Also you don't actually decorate anything in here.

Comment: @snb I didn't write a working decorate function yes but looking at the example it is kind of easy to understand that I want to create self-aware decorators to simply store their results inside a dict without having to call the functions myself. One solution would be to use reflection but I want to know if people know of a better way.

Comment: no it isn't easy to understand that you want to "create self-aware decorators to simply store their results inside a dict without having to call the functions", why not simply say that instead?.  Also when I said you didn't decorate anything, I meant that none of your syntax actually implies decoration, you don't modify and return functions with anything in your example, see JBernardo's answer, see this example for class decorators https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/python-class-decorators.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I found out a way to solve this, but this is not elegant.

I created a metaclass which will add the instance variable when the derived class is created:

```
import types


class MetaTemplateData(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, base, dct):
        orig_init = dct.get("__init__")
        decorators = []
        for _, value in dct.items():
            if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
                if value.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(value)
            elif isinstance(value, staticmethod):
                function = value.__func__
                if function.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(function)

        def init_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if orig_init:
                orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

            # pylint: disable=protected-access
            self._callbacks = getattr(self, "_callbacks", [])
            self._callbacks.extend(decorators)
        dct["__init__"] = init_wrapper
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, base, dct)
```

This is our decorator, this will call the function and check if is static or not and store its result in a new dict:

```
def add_content(key):
    def register_decorator(function):
        def _content_wrapper(self=None, *args, **kwargs):
            num_args = function.__code__.co_argcount
            if isinstance(function, types.FunctionType):
                if self and num_args != 0:
                    data = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    data = function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                data = function.__func__()
            return {key: data}
        return _content_wrapper
    return register_decorator
```

Than we can create a base class like this which takes care of calling all the decorated members for us and store its result inside a dict:

```
class Base(object, metaclass=MetaTemplateData):
    def __init__(self, email):
        self._email = email
        self._callbacks = []

    def parse(self):
        content = {}
        for func in self._callbacks:
            content.update(func(self))
        return content
```

Finally we get out derived class which will take care of adding content:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, email):
        super().__init__(email)
        self._name = name

    @add_content("key_number_one")
    def something(self):
        return {
            "email": self._email
        }

    @add_content("key_two")
    def something_else(self):
        return {
            "email": "DAEMAIL" + self._email
        }

    @add_content("key_for_static")
    @staticmethod
    def _do_private_things():
        return {
            "oh lord": "hoho"
        }
```

Now when we create a instance of the derived class, the magic happens:

```
derived = Derived("John", "some@email.com")
content = derived.parse()
print(content)
```

Result:

> {'key_for_static': {'oh lord': 'hoho'}, 'key_number_one': {'email': 'some@email.com'}, 'key_two': {'email': 'DAEMAILsome@email.com'}}

You can also call all the members from outside and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply define the decorator as an outside function (It can be done inside the class but feels cumbersome):

```
def register(key):
    def register_decorator(function):
        def fn(self, *args, **kw):
            out = function(self, *args, **kw)
            self.register(key, out)
        return fn
    return register_decorator
```

And the use it like this:

```
class BlaBla(Base):
    ...

    @register
    def do_something(self):
        return {"name": "yes"}
```

Also your `Base.register` function should receive 3 arguments: `self`, `key` and `output` which is the output from the method ran (instead of the method itself)

Comment: Well this does't work, not getting any outputs. Did you try this yourself?

Comment: I wanted to avoid a explicit call to do_something(), this only works if i call do_something(). I want a implicit call to do_something when i register the decorator or when i call run_them_all().